# How to share image from adapter using file provider

Tags: java, android

The images i want to share are stored in the drawable.
I read the image through adapter as i made arraylist of images.
I am trying to share image using file provider. If i want to share with maybe Gmail or WhatsApp etc, i will not see image.
How do source the image from hashmap "iImage"

**In MainActivity i made int for list of images in drawable**

```
//Listview icons for song titles in position
icon = new int[]{R.drawable.flower1, R.drawable.flower2, R.drawable.flower3, R.drawable.flower4, R.drawable.flower5, R.drawable.flower6, R.drawable.flower7, R.drawable.flower8, R.drawable.flower9, R.drawable.flower10};
```

**This is what i have in the Adapter that sends the image to DetailActivity**

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder7 myHolder, int i) {

        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); //here is position
        myHolder.mDesc.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
        myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon());
        myHolder.mSubImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon2());// here we used imge resource

        myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener7() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                String gTitle = models.get(position).getTitle();
                String gDesc = models.get(position).getDesc();
                int imageId = models.get(position).getIcon();



                //get our data with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity7.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", models.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", models.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("iImage", imageId);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return;
            }
        });

   }
```

This is what displayed the image in the **DetailActivity.java** i want to share using file provider

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageFoot1);
        if (intent != null && !intent.getExtras().isEmpty()) {
            imageResourceId = intent.getIntExtra("iImage", -1);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
        }
```

**NOW THIS IS HOW I SHARED THAT FAILED ME**

**I have configured the Manifest this below**

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
        </provider>
```

**This is the xml/file_paths file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**And this is my share Code** How do fix the exact hashmap that displayed the image through adapter for example this:  `imageResourceId = intent.getIntExtra("iImage", -1);` so that it will read the mage through the position through the adapter.

```
 buttonShare = findViewById(R.id.btnImageShare);
        buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Drawable drawable=imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

                try {
                    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir(), File.separator +"iImage");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    file.setReadable(true, false);
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider", file);

                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setType("image/png");

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Try removing `startActivity(shareIntent);` as you are already starting the activity using the Intent Chooser.

Comment: I removed startActivity(sharedIntent) yet no action on button click. I have edited and posted full code. I'm glad you are helping

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: No Sir, i didn't get any error. I see no action on button click

Comment: I have posted the error i see on button click from the Logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I have got it right!!! I'm very happy now. It is good to always apply effort so as to achieve aim.

If you are using Recylerview Adapter to pass image in full to DetailActivity, this solution will help you share the image received in DetailActivity so that you can share with social media apps.

**This is how i received the image from Adapter with intent put extrass into DetailActivity**

```
imageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageFoot1);
        if (intent != null && !intent.getExtras().isEmpty()) {
            imageResourceId = intent.getIntExtra("iImage", -1);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
        }
```

**This is the Correct Image Share Code**

```
Drawable drawable=imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

                try {
                    File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir(), File.separator +"iImage"+imageResourceId+".png");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    file.setReadable(true, false);
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider", file);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setType("image/png");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

It throws **FileNotFoundException** and the permission access is denied

```
2020-08-15 07:29:01.103 10745-10745/com.joseph.imagesshareW/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/share_image_1597472941101.png (Permission denied)
```

get user pemission for storage

**In your manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**ask runtime permission** [read through for how to request permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) Here the code
[For Asking runtime permission](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-request-permissions-in-android-application/)

Or you can give manually permission for app in setting then try
I hope it will work

Comment: I have these permission in Manifest file already. Must I configure manual permission settings to enable it work?

Comment: @Joseph go to settings->installed app->your app->app permissions->enable storage permission then try

Comment: I think i have found something close to what I want can you help me achieve it?

Comment: Bro this error is only because of you haven't gave permission to your app to access storage so after running your app in your emulator go to settings->apps->your app->permissions->enable storage permission check whether its working if it works then you can ask runtime permission from user [for asking runtime permission-code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-request-permissions-in-android-application/)

Comment: Please sir i have updated my question with your direction. Please take a look at the OP . thanks I'm expecting your solution

Comment: Please I await your direction based on the new development in the OP above

Comment: Please you can edit and make it your answer so that i can accept as best solution. Thanks in anticipation